# Triggered Email Send Sends Email Twice

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, cloudpage

I have a Cloudpage that takes a value, processes some logic and sends an email. Unfortunately, it sends two emails when it should send one.

```
%%[
VAR @sfid, @contactId, @centre, @email, @subLanguage, @rowCountSub, @subscriptionRow, @subscription, @contact, @rowCountCon, @contactRow, @today, @valid, @emailaddr, @ts, @tsDef, @ts_sub, @ts_statusCode, @errorCode
SET @sfid = REQUESTPARAMETER('sk')
SET @exp = REQUESTPARAMETER('exp')
SET @today = FormatDate(Now(), 'yyyy-MM-dd')

SET @subscription = RetrieveSalesforceObjects('MAG_Subscription__c', 'MAG_Language__c, MAG_Centre__c, MAG_Contact__c', 'Id', '=', @sfid)
SET @rowCountSub = rowCount(@subscription)

IF @rowCountSub > 0 THEN

    SET @subscriptionRow = Row(@subscription, 1)
    SET @subLanguage = FIELD(@subscriptionRow, 'MAG_Language__c')
    SET @contactId = FIELD(@subscriptionRow, 'MAG_Contact__c')
    SET @centre = FIELD(@subscriptionRow, 'MAG_Centre__c')

ENDIF

SET @contact = RetrieveSalesforceObjects('Contact', 'Email', 'Id', '=', @contactId)
SET @rowCountCon = rowCount(@contact)

IF @rowCountCon > 0 THEN

    SET @contactRow = Row(@contact, 1)
    SET @email = FIELD(@contactRow, 'Email')

ENDIF


IF @exp > @today THEN
  SET @valid = TRUE
ELSE
 SET @valid = FALSE
ENDIF

IF @centre == 'Athens' and @valid == TRUE THEN
  SET @ts = CreateObject("TriggeredSend")
  SET @tsDef = CreateObject("TriggeredSendDefinition")

  SetObjectProperty(@tsDef, "CustomerKey", "test_trigger_2")
  SetObjectProperty(@ts, "TriggeredSendDefinition", @tsDef)

  SET @ts_sub = CreateObject("Subscriber")
  SetObjectProperty(@ts_sub, "EmailAddress", @email)
  SetObjectProperty(@ts_sub, "SubscriberKey", @contactId)

  AddObjectArrayItem(@ts, "Subscribers", @ts_sub)

  SET @ts_statusCode = InvokeCreate(@ts, @ts_statusMsg, @errorCode)

ELSE
  SET @ts = CreateObject("TriggeredSend")
  SET @tsDef = CreateObject("TriggeredSendDefinition")

  SetObjectProperty(@tsDef, "CustomerKey", "test_trigger_1")
  SetObjectProperty(@ts, "TriggeredSendDefinition", @tsDef)

  SET @ts_sub = CreateObject("Subscriber")
  SetObjectProperty(@ts_sub, "EmailAddress", @email)
  SetObjectProperty(@ts_sub, "SubscriberKey", @contactId)

  AddObjectArrayItem(@ts, "Subscribers", @ts_sub)

  SET @ts_statusCode = InvokeCreate(@ts, @ts_statusMsg, @errorCode)
ENDIF
]%%
```

No idea why but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you adding contacts to a triggered send data extension?

Comment: The triggered email send set up includes a data extension, which is being updated every time an email is sent.

Comment: Thanks . did you create this data extension from a template?

Comment: Yes. template is a triggered email send template.

Comment: The the problem. The template will send emails automatically so you don’t need and use that bit of code you would just need to add them to the data extension. An alternative would be to use a normal de to send this

Comment: @Data_Kid - that isn't right. The data is added to the TSD DE via the Triggered API call as well as adding the send to your sending queue.  Adding data into the TSD DE in any other way will not trigger the email to send. These are two separate events that are executed via the same API.

Comment: Is it a duplicated email, or two different versions?